# Intuition for the convergence of the distance vector routing protocols

Tags: graphs, routing, protocols

What is an intuitive way to think about the convergence of the distance vector routing algorithm?

According to Wikipedia:

> Distance-vector routing protocols use the Bellman–Ford algorithm and Ford–Fulkerson algorithm to calculate the best route.

I am aware of the Bellman-Ford and Ford-Fulkerson algorithms and have some intuition for how and why they work. Unfortunately, I fail to see how they relate to the asynchronous distributed distance vector algorithm and so I lack intuition about why it converges.

Comment: Can you see how a distance-vector routing protocols can use the Bellman–Ford algorithm?

Comment: I guess that the Bellman-Ford algorithm could be used in a centralized manner and compute the shortest paths from a router to all other for each router in the network.

Comment: @Apass.Jack is there a way to improve the question so it gets more active and I get some insight?

Comment: Have you tried proving that the (basic version of) distance-vector routing protocol works for a connected network with a static topology and weights?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, no, I have not tried to prove the correctness of the algorithm. A formal proof would be useful, but I am more interested in the intuition behind it. Providing a formal proof and commenting on it will suffice.